# Cannot log in into server by any user

Tags: linux, opensuse

I have got a strange problem with one of my servers. The server is running but I cannot log in into it by any user.

I found that when I will reboot server it works for some time and then I cannot again log in into it. There is not anything in logs what could tell me what is wrong.

Does anyone know what should I check etc.?

The server is on Suse Enterprise Server 11.

Comment: So you *can* log in with root, but not with any other account? Or did you check your logs in some other way and you can't log in with the root account either?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that I cannot log in with root and any other account.

Comment: It might be helpful to describe what happens when you try to login to the server.

Comment: The usual approach is then to connect to the console (using your virtualisation manager if a virtual server, or DRAC, ILO, KVM or plain old monitor and keyboard) reboot into single user mode bypassing password protection and start debugging from there. If you dind't break anything by accident, by patching or on purpose and the system hasn't been compromised, one problem could be a completely full filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get into your system. It can be done with an

```
init=/bin/bash
```

into your kernel boot parameters. After booting, you get a root shell without authentication, but nothing other.

Second thing to do, is to make your system running (thus debuggable), while you have further your root shell. It can be done in two steps. First, you need to open a char console, with the command

```
openvt -c 23 -f /bin/bash
```

It will open a second root shell on your 23rd virtual console, which you can reach pressing an alt/leftarrow on your first virtual console (later, from X, you can get to this first virtual console with an alt/ctrl/f1).

After that, you can start your system with the command

```
exec /sbin/init
```

If all went OK, your system now runs, you can't further log in, but you can soon at least try them, while you have a root console at tty23.

Now try to log in, and check the logfiles in /var/log, what it says. If it is not enough to find and eliminate the problem, this site is waiting you with your next question and interesting error log parts.